# Place element correctly in place in array of ascending order

Tags: arrays, sorting, binary-search, solidity

I'm working with [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/), a very basic, Turing-complete language without the fancy prototype array functions offered to it by other languages such as `find` in JavaScript. I also have to make this placement function make as many loops or recursions (which is allowed in Solidity) as possible, as the process is using a thing called "gas" which is a fraction of the cryptocurrency.

Basically, I have to place an element in an ascending order array correctly so that the element before it is smaller and the element in front of it is bigger. And if the element I'm trying to place is equal to an element it's found, then simply to return the position of that element. I don't expect a lot of elements in this array, never more than a 1000, but even a 100 elements and a full 100 iterations is **extremely costly**, and since all lookup costs are user-side, it's in my benefit to make this as efficient as possible.

I understand sorting algorithms but what we're using here is a pre-sorted array, as each element that will be added to this array will be sorted one by one over time. Now, what I've come up with is and I don't know the name for this, to divide the array length by half,  do a conditional; compare it the next value or the value beneath it and then divide the or multiply the divisional by half it's value, then check the neighbors again and multiply or divide by half, the half of the divisional and so on until I get the correct value.

Will this work? What is this called?

For reference

```
function FindSpotinArray(uint256 price,
    uint256 divisionVariable, 
    uint256[] priceArray) returns (uint256) {
    if(price < priceArray[x] && priceArray != priceArray[x]) {
        divisionVariable * 2;
        var x = priceArray / divisionVariable;
    } else if (price > priceArray[x] && priceArray != priceArray[x]) {
        divisionVariable / 2;
        var x = priceArray / divisionVariable;
    } else if (price == priceArray[x]) {
        return x;
    } else if (priceArray[x - 1] <= priceArray[x] <= priceArray[x + 1]) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: You're using `x` before you assign it.

Comment: Yes, this code is far from complete, thank you for the answer.